# Помогите разобраться с циклом внутри цикла

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

Цикл в данный момент проходит по JSON ответу от обработчика и выводит div-ы с датами(date.date) и в каждом из них **все** свободные интервалы(interval.start). Необходимо выводить div с датой и свободными интервалами **именно на эту** дату.

```
      success: function(data) {
      let json = JSON.parse(data);
      const schedules = json["doctors"]["schedules"];

      for (let k = 0; k < json["doctors"].length; k++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < json["doctors"][k]["schedules"].length; i++) {
          const date = json["doctors"][k]["schedules"][i];
          console.log(date.date);
          $(".text-data").append($('<div>', {
            'class': "date",
            'text': date.date
          }));
        
          for (let j = 0; j < json["doctors"][k]["schedules"][i]["intervals"].length; j++) {
            const interval = json["doctors"][k]["schedules"][i]["intervals"][j];
            if(interval.free) {
              console.log(interval.start);
            $(".date").append($('<div>', {
            'class': "start",
            'text': interval.start
          }));
            }
          }}
      }}
```

Пожалуйста помогите!

Answer (score 0):

Вдуплил сам)

```
      success: function(data) {
      let json = JSON.parse(data);
      const schedules = json["doctors"]["schedules"];

      for (let k = 0; k < json["doctors"].length; k++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < json["doctors"][k]["schedules"].length; i++) {
          const date = json["doctors"][k]["schedules"][i];
          console.log(date.date);
          $(".text-data").append($('<div>', {
            'id': [i],
            'class': "date",
            'text': date.date
          }));
        
          for (let j = 0; j < date["intervals"].length; j++) {
            const interval = date["intervals"][j];
            if(interval.free) {
              console.log(interval.start);
            let iddate = "#" + [i];
            $(iddate).append($('<div>', {
            'class': "start",
            'text': interval.start
          }));
            }
          }}
      }}
```

Comment: [Разница](https://www.diffchecker.com/SNts2Stl), кому интересно =)